# Update query for products on category grid

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.4, magento2.4.5

on Magento 2.4.5, I've created a store view where only some users can log-in and the category products listed will be different for each user. But it's not working properly because the pagination is showing pages even if there are no more than 10 results (which is the limit I've configured), and the rest of the pages show the same filtered products.

I've created a preference `etc/frontend/di.xml`

```
class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
```

Which has the method

```
public function _getProductCollection()
{
    // Some code check before logic

    if ($this->_productCollection === null) {
        $this->_productCollection = $this->initializeProductCollection();
    }

    $productsArray = $this->myCustomRepository->getAllByUser($myAttribute)->toArray();
    $productRows = \array_column($productsArray['items'], 'row_id');

    $this->_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('row_id', ['in' => $productRows]);

    return $this->_productCollection;
}
```

Questions:

- Is this the right place to make this "update"
- If it is, why is the pagination not working properly or how I have to do it? Is there something i'm missing?

If you need more information just let me know. Thanks!